# Упакованный в контейнер Docker выдаёт HTTP 400

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, devops

Я упаковал в контейнер Docker приложение на Django и сервер postgreSQL. Через команду "ifconfig" я узнал вывод контейнеров Docker и обратился на "http://172.17.0.1:8000/", однако получил код состояния HTTP 400. Посоветуйте, что делать?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose: 
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: ldxi
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 14037176
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db_data:/etc/db_data

  blog:
    restart: always
    build: ./source
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - app_data:/etc/app_data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "ldxi", "-d", "db"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s

volumes:
  db_data:
  app_data:
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

print(BASE_DIR)


SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-v%9f9y&*ppef$_uo6)*5%)k6q-&e5sdh*#nq+$qrabz469oem#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["0.0.0.0"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',

    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'some_site.urls'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'ldxi',
        'PASSWORD': '14037176',
        'HOST': '172.17.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'some_site.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases





# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Base url to serve media files 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
 
# Path where media is stored 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY r.txt /app
RUN pip install -r r.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8080
CMD python3 manage.py migrate;python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```